# Troubleshooting an unmaintained Java app, JStylo?

Tags: java, maven, linguistics

I found a pretty phenomenal tool (that's [been abandoned](https://github.com/psal/jstylo/issues/12#issuecomment-226476041)) called [JStylo](https://github.com/psal/jstylo) and has a sister tool called Anonymouth.  Their goals are to test authorship and to anonymize authorship of writings.

When I build the project with Maven (`mvn package`), it seems to build (there are some errors that don't seem to stop the build process), but when I execute it via `java -Xmx2048m -jar jstylo-2.9.0.jar`

I get:

`no main manifest attribute, in jstylo-2.9.0.jar`

and when I execute the `jstylo-2.9.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar` package, I get:

```
ERROR GUIMain - Look-and-Feel error!
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jgaap/generics/LanguageParsingException
    at edu.drexel.psal.jstylo.GUI.GUIMain.initData(GUIMain.java:266)
    at edu.drexel.psal.jstylo.GUI.GUIMain.<init>(GUIMain.java:259)
    at edu.drexel.psal.jstylo.GUI.GUIMain$1.run(GUIMain.java:249)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jgaap.generics.LanguageParsingException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 17 more
```

Any thoughts on what may be going on here or how to dig in and troubleshoot this further?

Comment: From the [project page](https://github.com/psal/jstylo):  `NOTE: JStylo depends on JGAAP, which is not hosted on the maven central repository. Additionally, due to github's policy on large files, it cannot be included with the project.`  Looks like you may need [JGAAP](http://evllabs.com/?page_id=42) installed

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but I just discovered JStylo myself. After building it, from the base directory type:

```
java -cp lib\jgaap-5.2.0-lite.jar;target\jstylo-2.9.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar edu.drexel.psal.jstylo.GUI.GUIMain
```